# SabreCSG in Unity3D can't make build (error CS0246: The type or namespace name '***' could not be found)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, build, sabre, csg

I have tried in several ways (even created empty project and installed sabreCSG in my unity).
I am using unity 2017.4.3, Unity 2019.3.6 and Unity 2020 latest version as well.
It runs normally in editor but when I tried to make build or stand-alone exe, It gives me these errors.
Where is mistake? My player settings are also normal

error CS0246: The type or namespace name '***' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you change something in [that script](https://github.com/sabresaurus/SabreCSG/blob/master/Scripts/Core/CSG/Polygon.cs)? It seems that usually it shouldn't even be compiled if not inside the Unity Editor. Which makes sense since it is a tool for building levels .. so I think you wouldn't need it at runtime right? `primarily a level creation tool to be used inside Unity. In addition to that however, it’s possible to create brushes, manipulate them and build geometry in the editor through scripting. This is a quick guide to how that works. Please note: this feature is considered beta`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been solved finally. The solution is:
SabreCSG are using scripting command "RUNTIME_CSG" for build.

[image]

Because I am using SabreCSG plugin through scripting, so I need to define Scripting symbol in Player Settings.
Goto **Player Settings** >> **Other Settings** >> **Define Scripting Symbol**
and Add scripting symbol "**RUNTIME_CSG**" will solve this issue

[image]